# Can't Open .FXML File in SceneBuilder

Tags: eclipse, javafx

I am trying to make a JavaFX program, but the .FXML file won't open. It gives me the error: "Opening the file with SceneBulider failed. Try setting the absolute path to scenebuilder in the your preferences." If any of you know how to fix this, please post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you will open Scene Builder directly and then go to file->browse you can open the .fxml file from your file directory  on your computer. I had a similar issue in netbeans. If that doesn't work, get an older version of scene builder. There should only be two available versions at this time that I know of.

Comment: But, how do I open it directly?

Comment: When you installed/downloaded Scene Builder, it came with an executable jar. Check the folder you downloaded to find that jar file.

Comment: I just searched every file, but no executable file that I could run came up. What's the name of the file?

Comment: I'm sorry, I told you wrong. Its actually an exe file. I am looking at it on my windows 8 pc now. I found it here.. C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0\ The file name is called JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0.exe

Comment: It's not there for some reason.

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: You need to be using Version 8 Update 45. That could be the entire issue.

Comment: java fx wasn't introduced until java 8

Comment: I am using update 45. Also, I searched for the file in that location,but I got no results. However, when I go to uninstall a program, Java FX Scene Builder 2.2.21 comes up. Unfortunately, though, I can't find the path or open it from there.

Comment: Try downloading the scene builder again from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/javafxscenebuilder-1x-archive-2199384.html  check to see if that directory or any file related to scene Builder exists on your drive. It has to be somewhere. Maybe try searching your file directory for Scene Builder2.0 after your reinstall.

Comment: I tried to reinstall, but now it won't even let me try to open it with Scene Builder.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle no longer updates SceneBuilder. This means that your FXML can contain new unsupported elements like the Spinner. This could cause the SceneBuilder to fail.

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse go to Windows>Preferences

then Chose JavaFX,

Gave path of executable SceneBuilder
your scene builder path can be on this path directory /br

C:\Users\\AppData\Local\SceneBuilder

or

C:\Program Files(x86)\Oracle\JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0

and chose Scene builder executable file.

if can't find it there, then go to this link and install SceneBuilder in you local machine

https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/